# Receiving legit emails into spam folder

Tags: outlook.com, email

On my `@hotmail` address, I'm receiving emails from a specific `person-i-know@gmail.com` address into spams, despite having the expeditor in my contact list.

Not all the emails from this address directly go into spams, some of them go in the filtered folder I created (it may depend on whether it's a reply, a new email, or a reply to all, I don't really remember noticing a pattern).

Marking every email as not being spam doesn't change anything for the next ones I'll receive.

Is there something I can do? Because the emails are deleted after a short period (that seems totally random, sometimes it's 30 days, sometimes it's 7 seven days, some of them have no countdown).